# How to calculate the communication cost of messages and signatures?

Tags: signature

It is mentionned [here](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/12/10/1687/htm) that this message–signature tuple {PIDi, mi, Ti, σi} has this size:
40 + 20 × 3 + 8 = 104 bytes.
Can someone explain to me how this was calculated?

Comment: Could you please create a more precise reference to a section within that document? Note that questions should be able to survive even without links, so please also include more of the source material in the question.

Comment: it could be misprinted. if not , you read through entire document and you may get better idea.